# Merge [gpg] and [gnupg]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Unless there is a second definition for the abbreviation GPG that I'm not aware of, I believe the tags [gpg](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpg) and [gnupg](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnupg) should be merged as identical (and have one be a synonym of the other, I would recommend doing the same as [*SuperUser* and prefer `gnupg`](https://superuser.com/tags/gnupg/synonyms))

Could someone with more reputation make it so?

Comment: Agree, and done.